# VSCode Kotlin Spring error: unresolved reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, visual-studio-code

im trying to learn using Kotlin with Spring from here : https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/

When im trying to run BlogApplication.kt it gives me this error :

```
[Running] cd "h:\Reshong\blog\src\main\kotlin\com\example\blog\" && kotlinc BlogApplication.kt -include-runtime -d BlogApplication.jar && java -jar BlogApplication.jar
BlogApplication.kt:3:12: error: unresolved reference: springframework
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
           ^
BlogApplication.kt:4:12: error: unresolved reference: springframework
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
           ^
BlogApplication.kt:6:2: error: unresolved reference: SpringBootApplication
@SpringBootApplication
 ^
BlogApplication.kt:11:2: error: unresolved reference: runApplication
    runApplication<BlogApplication>(*args) 
 ^
BlogApplication.kt:13:4: error: unresolved reference: setBannerMode
      setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF)
   ^
BlogApplication.kt:13:18: error: unresolved reference: Banner
      setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF)
                 ^

[Done] exited with code=1 in 3.087 seconds
```

I already tried a lot of googling and i dont find any result that helped me.

Here's my code :

```
package com.example.blog

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class BlogApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) 
{
    runApplication<BlogApplication>(*args) 
    {
      setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF)
    }
}
```

Im still learning, so any help and advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Your dependencies are missing, usually people use [maven](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/) or [gradle](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/) with spring. Follow those directions depending on what you are using.

Comment: `pom.xml` or `build.gradle.kts` in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Search [springframework](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/5.3.9) in [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/), you can get the following page:

[image]

If there's `pom.xml` in your project, copy the content shown below the option **Maven** to `pom.xml`;

If it's `build.gradle.kts`, copy the one in the option **Gradle(Kotlin)** to `build.gradle.kts`.

After adding all missing dependencies, rebuild the project and run again.

**Reference**: [Java build tools in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build)